# How to start notepad.exe in hidden mode in windows application?

Tags: c#

I am trying to start notepad.exe in hidden mode like below is the code which i have written:-

```
try
{
     ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
     startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
     startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
     startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
     startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Users\Sujeet\Documents\test.txt";
}
catch
{ 

}
```

but the problem is process(i.e. notepad.exe) gets successfully started but startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden is not working.
I have surfed net for this problem but was not able to get the proper solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden mode"? Not visible in taskbar?

Comment: `startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` won't work if you use `startInfo.UseShellExecute = false`.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: yes, the application should be running but not visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version works on my box:

```
try
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.FileName = @"%windir%\system32\notepad.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Users\Sujeet\Documents\test.txt";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
catch
{ }
```

I only get a Win32Exception telling that the file (test.txt) cannot be found, but the process runs, and no window is visible.

Take care to exit the process, or the user will end up with invisible processes running.

If your application is uncooperative (like calc.exe you mentioned in the comments), you could try the following:

Define somewhere:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
    const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
```

And then do the following after crating the process:

```
    var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
    while (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) //note: only works as long as your process actually creates a main window.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, SW_HIDE);
```

I don't know why the path `%windir%\system32\calc.exe` does not work, but it works with `startInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\calc.exe";`

Comment: @Antara Are you sure? It only appears inside TaskManager or ProcessExplorer or similar programs. 

If it really does not show up, do you get any Exceptions?

Comment: but if i replace the notepad.exe path with calc.exe its not working, Why is this happening?? any suggestion

Comment: You need to supply the correct path to your executable. On my machine `%windir%\system32\calc.exe` works as well. Maybe your calc.exe is in another directory?

Comment: I have tested the same code for wordpad.exe and mspaint.exe and its working perfectly fine but my question is why its not working for calc.exe.

Comment: Perhaps you still have `startInfo.Arguments` defined?

Comment: Dominik, I have commented the startInfo.Arguments line in my code.

Comment: azt, I have mentioned the correct address of calc.exe and its in the same directory. Please help !!

Comment: @Antara I'm testing the code right now. It seems that to start the calculator itself you need to use `startInfo.FileName = "calc"`, however, I didn't manage to make it invisible yet.

Comment: @Dominik  Okey, I am also trying to get it solved by today only.

Comment: Extended the answer to make calc.exe work. If it works for you, I'd appriciate if you upvote the answer.

Comment: Thanks @azt, Do you know why first code you submitted for notepad is not working with calc.exe. Any specific reason for this why we have to create the window handle for calculator to run in hidden mode.

Comment: Sorry, don't know why calc does not respect the starting parameters. But I guess it is up to the application to conform with the standard.